# how to read a file from a Jar file located on remote server

Tags: java

I want to read and copy file from jar file(for eg. application.xml from  EAR )located on remote server to local machine. when i search on net for this, i found java.util.jar.JarFile API. This API read jar only from local machine as it takes only string as input and not URL for jar location in constructor.    I know  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient API.This API can copy any file or even jar from remote server to local machine. But my requirement is to copy only single file from jar  located on remote server.

Please help me in this regard .

Thanks
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have a better luck if you try creating your own downloading mechanism, something along these lines:

```
    ZipInputStream zip = null;
    try {
        zip = new ZipInputStream(url.openStream());

        ZipEntry entry;
        do{
            entry = zip.getNextEntry();
        } while(!yourExpectedFileName.equals(entry.getName())


        while(zip.available()){
             //read your data
        }
        zip.closeEntry();

    } finally {
        if (zip != null)
            zip.close();
    }
```

Comment: The server is refusing to let me edit my question, but make sure you check for `null` on the first while to end the loop if the file is not found.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. i am now able to read and copy  application.xml from EAR from remote machine to local machine . but i also want to read  MANIFEST.MF only of each jar/war(not complete jar/war) present in EAR . above code only give entry for jar and war inside EAR.  for above case i got InputStream  using com.jcraft.jsch.* API. My remote server is SFTP so i  have used jsch api for InputStream. but now how to get InputStream  for each jar and war inside EAR as jsch API is not able to give you InputStream for war/jar inside EAR?

Comment: @SameerPansare I don't think that's possible, and I'm almost sure you'll have to download the whole .jar (located inside the .ear) to read it's manifest.mf.

Comment: @ Marcelo, I think you are right. I marked you answer as right. thanks again.